# Summarising/grouping excel rows based on key column while performing calculations

Tags: excel

I am attempting to merge/group rows with the same trade_id while summing their values in the amount (F) tab and potentially doing other calculations with each row's related data. What is the best way to go about this in Excel?

[image]

I expect it to look something like this the bottom-most row of the below screenshot, but for each and every row with a unique trade_id. So far, I've tried using filters, pivot tables and data consolidation, but have not been able to achieve the desired result.

[image]

Comment: Research Power Query probably.

Comment: *group rows with the same trade_id while summing their values in the amount (F) tab* is, indeed, Pivot Tables. *other calculations with each row's related data* is unclear, depending on those calculations you may need something else.